# How do I return this ruby array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a table named `Player` in my Rails app, and on the table, there are seven boolean attributes.

```
monday: true, tuesday: false, wednesday: true, thursday: false, friday: false, saturday: true, sunday: false
```

What is the best way to return an array with all the days that are true with `ActiveRecord`? I want to return:

```
["monday", "wednesday", "saturday"]
```

Any ideas on an efficient way to do this? I am drawing a blank? `Player.first.map`?

Comment: Pls. tell the structure of Player table/ the table in which `monday:true    ... ` data is there a little bit more..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you mean that there are 7 attributes on the model you could add a method to `Player` like

```
def days
  ["monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", 
    "saturday", "sunday"].select { |day| attributes[day] }
end
```

So for your example it would just be

```
Player.first.days # => e.g. ["monday", "wednesday", "saturday"]
```

---

This is making use of the ActiveRecord `attributes` method on a model instance which returns a `Hash` of attribute names to values.

---

As [InternetSeriousBusiness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1558513/internetseriousbusiness) has commented, there is already an array of the day names defined on the `Date` class so you could use that and avoid listing the days yourself, but note that the days in there start with an initial capital letter so you'd need a `downcase` to match your attribute names e.g.

```
Date::DAYNAMES.select { |day| attributes[day.downcase] }
```

Comment: You can use Date::DAYNAMES as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this issue with something like:

```
p = Player.first

p.attributes.select{|k,v| v == true}.keys
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What if you add boolean column `playing` in players table?